# View Pager с динамической подгрузкой данных

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-viewpager, recyclerview.adapter

View Pager с динамической подгрузкой данных из сети. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при добавлении новых данных создаются дополнительные фрагменты, что очень сильно расходует память. 
Как сделать так, чтобы использовались уже созданные фрагменты? Но при этом необходимо чётко разграничить начальную и конечную страницу! (зацикленный View Pager не нужен)
Такая логика уже есть в recycler view. Но проблема в том, что мне нужно использовать View Pager или любые его наследники. Если нужно писать свой адаптер, то прошу привести пример. За раннее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть же метод хороший - `setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int) устанавливается лимит в обе стороны, старые фрагменты автоматически удаляются.

Comment: Да, это то что было нужно, спасибо большое!